# what is the best practice for committing lots of small styling changes? Should i use branches?

Tags: css, version-control, styling

I am styling an app while changes are still being made to the back end. Most of what I'm doing now is 'fine tuning' and minor fixes and am producing anywhere between 3 and 20 commits a day, many of which are completely unrelated to each other.

I'm currently doing all my commits to the master branch.

My changes include mostly css and HTML changes.

heres a few examples of my recent commit messages:

```
add complete 'with bars' animation for all audios

add link to feed in navbar

show events in main feed

add 'share' link to audio_text_post

activate audio comment collapse for all instances

reposition share buttons for images

clean up audio footer css

show like count only when > 0
```

Should i not be commiting to the master branch? I feel like its just taking away from the more significant back end commits. Should i be creating generic branches like style-1, style-2, etc?

Comment: If your infrastructure has MVC (model-view-controller) separation, your commits should not impact the back end. Stick to the trunk, otherwise you'll create a profusion of branches that will likely cause more grief for back-end and build devs in your team.

Comment: >  otherwise you'll create a profusion of branches: 

yep, this is why we stopped doing that. Just to clarify, you're saying to stick with just committing to master?

> your commits should not impact the back end: 

this wasn't my concern, I just don't like all my commits clogging up the feed alongside others that are much more important, or is this normal and not something i should care about?

Comment: Yes, I would commit to master. After all version control is there to track all changes, no matter how small or seemingly unimportant.